# is it possible to autofill a form in a website with data from google sheets using Laravel or any programming language?

Tags: php, laravel, api, google-sheets

I have created a Whatsapp chatbot using ManyChat that's ask the user to enter his **name** , **Email and Phone number** and after the user done with providing his info to the bot the user inputs will be saved to google sheets, and after that the chatbot will send the user a link to my website to finalize his request.
this link will take him to a form with the same field as in whatsapp (**name, Email and Phone Number**).

i want the form to be prefilled with the unique data of the user when the user click the link and goes to the form in my website. I have already integrated my website with google sheets API.
I just want to know if its possible and how to do it?

I want to try doing it using Token ID or Authentication ID but I Don't Know how to get it in my case

here's the code if you can find it helpful

**Google Sheets Services**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Services;

use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\Sheets;
use Google\Service\Sheets\Sheet;
use Google\Service\Sheets\ValueRange;

class GoogleSheetServices{
    public $client, $service, $documentId, $range;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client= $this->getClient();
        $this->service= new Sheets($this->client);
        $this->documentId= '*my document id here*';
        $this->range='A:Z';
    }
    public function getClient(){
        $client=new Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Google Sheet Demo');
        $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost::8000/googlesheet');
        $client->setScopes(Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
        $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');

        return $client;
    }
    public function readSheet(){

     $doc= $this->service->spreadsheets_values->get($this->documentId,$this->range);
     return $doc;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Google\Service\Sheets;
use App\Http\Services\GoogleSheetServices;
class GoogleSheetController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function sheetOperation(Request $request){
        $data=(new GoogleSheetServices ())->readSheet();
        return view('googlesheet',compact('data'));
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateGoogleOAuthsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('google_o_auths', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('provider');
            $table->string('provider_value');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('google_o_auths');
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Contact form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main-block">
        <div class="left-part">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-at"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-mail-bulk"></i>
        </div>
        @php
        foreach($data as $value){
        }
        @endphp
        <form action="/">
            <h1>Request for Multiple Qoutes</h1>
            <div class="info">
                <select name="select_category" id="select_categor">
                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                    <option value=>{{$value['0']}}</option>
                </select>
                <input class="fname" type="text" name="name" value={{$value['2']}} placeholder="Subject">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Email" value={{$value['3']}}>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Phone number" value={{$value['4']}}>
            </div>
            <p>Message</p>
            <div>
                <textarea rows="4">{{$value['1']}}</textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" href="/">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

here's the result of `$sheetData = dd(new GoogleSheetServices())->readSheet();`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes for sure you can populate your view with data in multiple ways, and your, using controller is the common one, I would just recommend some organization in your controller like so:

```php
$data = [];
$sheetData = (new GoogleSheetServices())->readSheet();

foreach ($sheetData as $value) {
    // Option 1: as Object
    $whatsAppUser = new \stdClass();
    $whatsAppUser->message = $value['1'];
    $whatsAppUser->name = $value['2'];
    $whatsAppUser->email = $value['3'];
    $whatsAppUser->phoneNumber = $value['4'];
    $data[] = $whatsAppUser;

    // Option 1: as Array
    $data[] = [
        'message' => $value['1'],
        'name' => $value['2'],
        'email' => $value['3'],
        'phoneNumber' => $value['4'],
    ];
}

return view('googlesheet', compact('data'));
```

If you are facing problems please update your answer with the result of `dd((new GoogleSheetServices())->readSheet());`

Edit:
Based on your comment, in your `googlesheet.blade` file:

```html
@foreach($data as $whatsAppUser)
<!-- if you choose option 1: -->
{{ $whatsAppUser->message }} 
{{ $whatsAppUser->name }}

<!-- if you choose option 2: -->
{{ $whatsAppUser['message'] }} 
{{ $whatsAppUser['name'] }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: i tried to your code but the form filed is empty now, theres no data on it , please see the result of dump and die

Comment: Okay Moe, I just updated my answer, and let me know so I can help as much as I can